# Is there a way to introduce Internet Explorer conditional comments using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, wicket, conditional-comments

I have a segment of HTML code which includes a conditional comment:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" ...>
<[endif]-->
```

This code was tested and works correctly when included in the HEAD section of the page, on the initial page rendering.

I would like to introduce the same conditional CSS to an existing page using JavaScript in an Ajax response.

I have tried:

```
var comment = document.createComment("[if IE]>\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" ...>\n<[endif]");
Wicket.Head.addElement(comment); //this is framework code that just appends the element to the HEAD node of the page. I debugged and verified that it's doing the appendChild(...) call.
```

The above code does not cause the stylesheet to be applied in Internet Explorer 7. Is there a way, using JavaScript, to introduce the conditional style in a way that Internet Explorer understands?

Just to be clear, I am trying to use JavaScript to create a conditional style, *not* trying to write browser-conditional JavaScript.

Comment: For one thing, your unescaped quotes are breaking your script. Notice the syntax highlighting of your CC string, near `"stylesheet"`. Also, the endif tag should start with `<![`, not `<[`.

Comment: [This article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/) may help you find a solution. Specifically, the **Alternate Stylesheet** section.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks for pointing out the quotes; I fixed the escaping. This wasn't the cause of my problem, though; in my actual use case, the text of the comment is loaded from an XML DOM object via ajax, and it's escaped automatically by the wicket framework. I know that the conditional comment string I'm using is not the source of the problem, since it works when inlined as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use conditional comments inside `innerHTML` as follows:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<!--[if IE]><i></i><![endif]-->";
if (div.getElementsByTagName("i").length) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.href = "ie_only.css";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: This looks like it addresses the problem. I will try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you know [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)?

Also, it is great to use this in the HTML open tag (replace the `no-js` with `js`!)

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html lang=en-us class="no-js ie6"><![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang=en-us class="no-js ie7"><![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang=en-us class="no-js ie8"><![endif]--> 
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang=en-us class=no-js> <!--<![endif]-->
```

So you can do this in CSS:

```
.ie7 .myDiv {
    foo:bar;
}
```

Can also be accessed in javascript with:

```
if( document.body.className.indexOf("ie") > -1 ){
     //
}

// or using jQuery

if( $(document.body).hasClass("ie6") ){
}
```

Comment: not strictly answering the question but a round about way of accessing the same information

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
/*@cc_on document.createStyleSheet("ie.css"); @*/
```

Answer (score 0):

All this is unnecessary.

public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response)
if (WebSession.get().getClientInfo().getClientProperties().isBrowserInternetExplorer()) {
  response.renderJavaScriptReference(new JavaScriptResourceReference(MyClass.class, "ie.js"));
}

If you choose to use Modernizr be aware of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3433