# Detecting what browser using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

How do I detect what browser a user is using in JQuery 1.9?

Comment: Google "How do I detect what browser a user is using in JQuery 1.9"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379539/whats-a-quick-pure-javascript-replacement-for-jquery-browser-removed-in-jquer

Comment: Take a look at this qustion. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14365725/1995997)

Comment: THe first link is the better option.

Comment: oops delete my answer below depreceated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jQuery.browser()` method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and is removed in 1.9. If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery Migrate plugin.

For more info refer this: [Changes of Note in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)

Recommend to use: http://modernizr.com/